# How to prioritize test classes in testng

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

How do i priotize the following suite to run in this specific order, when i run using eclipse it runs in this order but from cmd it runs alphabetically. Is there anyway that i can in this order in the command prompt.

```
<suite name="Groups Suite">
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="ww5.listener.Listener" />
</listeners>
<test name="Groups Suite Tests">
    <classes>
        <class name="ww5.testcases.groupsSuite.GoToGroupsPageTest" ></class> 
        <class name="ww5.testcases.groupsSuite.CreateNewGroupTest" ></class>
        <class name="ww5.testcases.groupsSuite.DeleteGroupTest" ></class>
        <class name="ww5.testcases.groupsSuite.SearchGroupTest" ></class> 
        <class name="ww5.testcases.groupsSuite.AddDevicesOrUsersToGroupTest"></class> 
        <class name="ww5.testcases.groupsSuite.RemoveDevicesFromGroupTest" ></class> 
        <class name="ww5.testcases.groupsSuite.RemoveUsersFromGroupTest" ></class> 

    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<test name="SAMPLE-TEST" preserve-order="true">
```

This should ensure that it is running in the specified order